# Autocad scaling

Tags: autocad, cad, autodesk

I'm studing AutoCAD and encountered with a scale problem.

I write a simple detail, but when i'm setting **Lineweight 1.00 mm** AutoCAD draw 2cm line instead of 1mm line. I tried to change scale in `Annotate -> Dimensions -> Scale factor = 0.05`, but it didn't help.

Here is two screenshots: how it is with and withoud LWB pressed. It does some crazy things when I want just to create a line a bit thicker than default.[image][image]

I have the same problem, but [this post](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-2010-2011-2012/lineweight-too-thick-when-plotting/td-p/3692068) wasn't very helpful
And [this post](http://forums.augi.com/showthread.php?21280-Lines-display-thick-in-paperspace) wasn't neither

I posed it gere according to this aricle that says, that SO is the best options for this kind of questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188052/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-autocad-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scale factor only controls the scale of the line*type*.

To change the way the line*weight* displays on the screen, right click on the "Show/Hide Lineweight" toggle at the very bottom, click "Settings..." and adjust the slider labelled "Adjust Display Scale".

Note that this will not change the printed weight of the lines, just how they show up on your monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the [Autodesk forums](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad/ct-p/8) is the best place to ask an AutoCAD setup question.

Both posts you linked to above (Autodesk forums and AUGI) pertain to plotting and/or PaperSpace but your post is clearly showing ModelSpace.

I would check if you've drawn your sketch using polylines with a defined width.  Could be a units issue as well.